# Calculating different outcomes in SQL for the same columns depending on another column

Tags: sql-server

I've been asked to provide a report showing the performance of an individual telephone agent by day across a timespan to be decided at runtime compared to the average of the department.
I've managed to create the main SQL to calculate totals for the days, grouped into the subject agent and the rest of the group.
The problem is that I need to use sum for the agent, but average (or at least be able to divide the answer by 13) for the remaining group.

I think Case is the answer but for the life of me, I can't see how. I've looked at multiple examples online but they all seem to deal with individual field values rather than differing calculations.

Here's what I have so far.

```
declare @Extension varchar(3) ='215'
select sum(inward) + sum(transfers) + sum(lost) as Incoming,sum(outgoing) as Outgoing,sum(transfers) as Transfers,sum(lost) as Lost,GRP,CallDate
from (
    select   
            CASE
            When extension in (@Extension) then 'Selected'
                When extension in('263','250','275','215','223','614','134','292','213','225','271','256','302')  then 'Main Office Housing'

                ELSE 'Unknown'
                END AS GRP,
            Cast(calltime as date) As CallDate,
            case when calltype='i' then 1 else 0 end as inward,
            case when calltype='o' then 1 else 0 end as outgoing,
            case when calltype='ia' then 1 else 0 end as lost,
            case when calltype = 'if' then 1 else 0 end as transfers
            From lrcalldetail  With (NOLOCK)  
            where calltime between DATEADD(d,-7,getdate()) and getdate()
    ) ALLCALLS
    where grp <>'UNKNOWN'
    Group by Allcalls.grp, ALLCALLS.CallDate
    Order by GRP,CallDate
```

It's driving me mad, no doubt someone will just knock it out the park.

Here's the ddl for the table in question.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[lrcalldetail](
[calldetailid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[cdrdataid] [int] NULL,
[recordingid] [int] NULL,
[calltime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[totalduration] [int] NULL,
[ringduration] [int] NULL,
[connectedduration] [int] NULL,
[channel] [varchar](50) NULL,
[extension] [varchar](50) NULL,
[callerid] [varchar](50) NULL,
[calledid] [varchar](50) NULL,
[team] [varchar](50) NULL,
[takenby] [varchar](50) NULL,
[cost] [float] NULL,
[type] [varchar](50) NULL,
[subtype] [varchar](50) NULL,
[transferfromcalldetailid] [int] NULL,
[calltype] [varchar](50) NULL,
[recordedtime] [datetime] NULL,
[linetype] [char](2) NULL,
[transfertocalldetailid] [int] NULL,
[calldirection] [char](1) NULL,
[dialduration] [int] NULL,
[site] [varchar](128) NULL,
[pbxcallid] [varchar](50) NULL,
[status] [varchar](50) NULL,
[trunk] [varchar](50) NULL,
[totaltrunkcalls] [int] NULL,
[recordingidmatchrating] [bigint] NULL,
[processstage] [int] NULL,
[dstchannel] [varchar](50) NULL,
[dsttrunk] [varchar](50) NULL,
[account] [varchar](50) NULL,
[accesscode] [varchar](50) NULL,
[internal] [char](1) NULL,
[destextension] [varchar](50) NULL,
[organisationguid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[groupid] [int] NULL,
[agentid] [varchar](50) NULL,
[endtime] [datetime] NULL,
[userid] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_lrcalldetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[calldetailid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and here is some example data

```
calltime                  extension   calltype   calldirection
2017-12-13 09:17:50.000   256         ia        I
2017-12-13 09:20:55.000   271         i         I
2017-12-13 09:21:36.000   271         i         I
2017-12-13 09:42:34.000   223         o         O
2017-12-13 09:42:50.000   215         ia        I
2017-12-13 09:43:50.000   263         ia        I
2017-12-13 09:47:57.000   225         i         I
2017-12-13 09:48:10.000   225         i         I
2017-12-13 09:48:50.000   256         ia        I
2017-12-13 09:55:31.000   215         o         O
2017-12-13 10:02:01.000   223         o         O
2017-12-13 10:02:50.000   250         ia        I
2017-12-13 10:03:50.000   215         ia        I
2017-12-13 10:03:50.000   225         ia        I
2017-12-13 10:05:48.000   215         i         I
2017-12-13 10:05:55.000   215         i         I
2017-12-13 10:06:51.000   250         if        I
2017-12-13 10:24:50.000   134         ia        I
2017-12-13 10:28:40.000   263         if        I
2017-12-13 10:37:57.000   223         o         O
2017-12-13 10:39:19.000   215         o         O
2017-12-13 10:41:57.000   223         o         O
2017-12-13 10:50:25.000   614         o         O
2017-12-13 10:51:36.000   614         o         O
2017-12-13 10:53:39.000   215         o         O
2017-12-13 10:58:50.000   134         ia        I
2017-12-13 10:59:57.000   614         o         O
2017-12-13 11:03:46.000   263         if        I
2017-12-13 11:10:27.000   256         if        I
2017-12-13 11:13:50.000   302         ia        I
2017-12-13 11:14:22.000   225         o         O
2017-12-13 11:16:50.000   256         ia        I
2017-12-13 11:17:18.000   614         ia        I
2017-12-13 11:17:50.000   256         ia        I
2017-12-13 11:18:36.000   614         i         I
2017-12-13 11:18:38.000   614         i         I
2017-12-13 11:23:33.000   614         i         I
2017-12-13 11:23:55.000   614         i         I
2017-12-13 11:24:25.000   614         o         O
2017-12-13 11:33:12.000   225         o         O
2017-12-13 11:40:18.000   271         if        I
2017-12-13 11:42:12.000   215         o         O
2017-12-13 11:43:56.000   614         i         I
2017-12-13 11:44:29.000   614         i         I
2017-12-13 11:50:31.000   250         o         O
2017-12-13 11:55:40.000   223         o         O
2017-12-13 11:56:50.000   256         ia        I
2017-12-13 12:01:50.000   134         ia        I
2017-12-13 12:06:50.000   302         ia        I
2017-12-13 12:36:50.000   250         ia        I
2017-12-13 12:37:50.000   250         ia        I
2017-12-13 13:01:50.000   256         ia        I
2017-12-13 13:01:50.000   256         ia        I
2017-12-13 13:11:50.000   250         ia        I
2017-12-13 13:16:50.000   225         ia        I
2017-12-13 13:28:50.000   302         ia        I
2017-12-13 13:31:50.000   223         ia        I
2017-12-13 13:53:50.000   275         ia        I
2017-12-13 13:57:50.000   292         ia        I
2017-12-13 13:58:50.000   302         ia        I
2017-12-13 14:00:50.000   302         ia        I
2017-12-13 14:13:50.000   250         ia        I
2017-12-13 14:20:48.000   614         o         O
2017-12-13 14:21:50.000   225         ia        I
2017-12-13 14:38:12.000   292         o         O
2017-12-13 14:39:22.000   263         if        I
2017-12-13 14:40:04.000   256         o         O
2017-12-13 14:45:52.000   302         i         I
2017-12-13 14:45:57.000   302         i         I
2017-12-13 14:48:17.000   256         o         O
2017-12-13 14:51:56.000   302         i         I
2017-12-13 14:52:39.000   302         i         I
2017-12-13 15:01:50.000   256         ia        I
2017-12-13 15:01:57.000   302         o         O
2017-12-13 15:07:43.000   223         if        I
2017-12-13 15:12:57.000   302         i         I
2017-12-13 15:12:58.000   302         i         I
2017-12-13 15:15:50.000   263         ia        I
2017-12-13 15:18:40.000   263         i         I
2017-12-13 15:18:57.000   263         i         I
2017-12-13 15:35:58.000   223         o         O
2017-12-13 15:41:56.000   275         i         I
2017-12-13 15:42:05.000   275         i         I
2017-12-13 15:44:07.000   223         o         O
2017-12-13 15:52:08.000   223         o         O
2017-12-13 15:55:42.000   223         o         O
2017-12-13 16:01:50.000   271         ia        I
2017-12-13 16:02:40.000   250         o         O
2017-12-13 16:15:30.000   223         o         O
2017-12-13 16:17:57.000   223         i         I
2017-12-13 16:18:07.000   223         i         I
2017-12-13 16:28:50.000   225         ia        I
2017-12-13 16:36:50.000   271         ia        I
2017-12-13 16:45:51.000   614         ia        I
2017-12-13 16:48:50.000   614         ia        I
2017-12-13 16:49:50.000   271         ia        I
2017-12-13 16:54:59.000   263         o         O
2017-12-13 16:55:09.000   263         o         O
2017-12-13 17:03:02.000   215         o         O
2017-12-13 17:18:28.000   225         o         O
2017-12-13 17:26:31.000   225         o         O
2017-12-14 08:37:27.000   302         o         O
2017-12-14 08:40:26.000   302         o         O
2017-12-14 08:44:45.000   263         o         O
2017-12-14 08:47:43.000   271         o         O
2017-12-14 09:21:50.000   256         ia        I
2017-12-14 09:26:33.000   225         o         O
2017-12-14 09:29:45.000   225         o         O
2017-12-14 09:35:39.000   225         o         O
2017-12-14 09:35:54.000   614         i         I
2017-12-14 09:35:57.000   614         i         I
2017-12-14 09:38:00.000   275         if        I
2017-12-14 09:44:21.000   225         o         O
2017-12-14 09:49:11.000   213         o         O
2017-12-14 09:51:52.000   614         o         O
2017-12-14 09:51:57.000   614         o         O
2017-12-14 09:55:28.000   614         o         O
2017-12-14 10:02:00.000   225         o         O
2017-12-14 10:05:49.000   225         o         O
2017-12-14 10:06:50.000   250         ia        I
2017-12-14 10:06:57.000   292         o         O
2017-12-14 10:07:02.000   292         o         O
2017-12-14 10:20:23.000   263         o         O
2017-12-14 10:26:23.000   614         if        I
```

Comment: what determines the agent? The `GRP`? Are your `Incoming`, and `Outgoing` totals accurate and you simply need to find the divisor?

Comment: What would really help is if you can provide the ddl for your table, some sample data that represent the problem and the desired result for that sample data. In the meantime you might want to take a peek at this article before you continue using NOLOCK all over the place. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for pointing out the nolock issue, I was under the impression that it was there to stop me freezing the table out while the main system tried to write to it but I stand corrected. I've added some further information to my original post. Sorry for the delay in replying but I was off on another project.

Answer (score 0):

If you include `extension` in your inner query then you can `COUNT(DISTINCT extension)` in your outer query to know how many extensions are in each `grp`. You can then divide the sums by this count to produce the average.

This will also calculate the average for the individual extension of interest - but since the average for a sample size of 1 is also equal to the sum, that should be fine.

(You'll either repeat the use of `COUNT(DISTINCT extension)` in each expression or introduce a further level of subquerying to allow you to write `Incoming/Cnt` - also watch out that it's likely that you're going to be working in integer math so you probably want to `CAST` to `decimal` or multiple by `1.0` to ensure you don't get integer truncation issues during the division)